# Sinon.js with Mongoose and bluebird

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, bluebird, sinon

I have a helper function that uses promisified Mongoose queries. I am fairly new to testing with Sinon.js, and can't figure out how to test Mongoose that uses bluebird Promises.

Here is my function:

```
module.exports = function addParticipant(session, user) {
Session.Promise = Promise;
return Session
    .findById(session._id)
    .populate('location')
    .populate('participants)
    .then((session) => {
        const participant = new Participant({
            user: user._id,
            session: session.id
        });
        return participant.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                Promise.reject(err);
            }
            session.participants.push(participant);
            session.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    Promise.reject(err);
                }
                notifications.notifyLearner(notifications.LEARNER_REGISTERED, {
                    session,
                    user
                });
                Promise.resolve(participant);
            });
        });
    });
 };
```

I want to test whether the student notification has been called or not, this is what I have, but I can't figure out how to mock the `then` portion of my promise chain.

```
describe('helpers', () => {
describe('addParticipant', () => {
    let SessionMock;

    beforeEach(() => {
        SessionMock = {
            populate: sinon.spy(() => SessionMock)
        };
        sinon.stub(Session, 'findById', () => SessionMock);
        sinon.stub(Session.prototype, 'save', (cb) => cb(null));
        sinon.stub(Participant.prototype, 'save', (cb) => cb(null));
        sinon.stub(notifications, 'notifyLearner');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        Session.findById.restore();
        Session.prototype.save.restore();
        Participant.prototype.save.restore();
        notifications.notifyLearner.restore();
    });

    describe('add participant to session', () => {
        let testSession;
        let testUser;
        let addParticipantPromise;

        beforeEach(() => {
            testUser = new User({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId
            });

            testSession = new Session({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                participants: []
            });
            // Probably not the best way to do this.
            SessionMock.then = sinon.spy((cb) => {
                cb(testSession);
            });
            addParticipantPromise = addParticipant(testSession, testUser);
        });

        it.only('should notify Learner', () => {
            return addParticipantPromise.then(() => {
                notifications.notifyLearner.should.be.called();
            });
        });
     });
   });
 });
```

I can pass my `testSession` into the the `then` function but nothing gets resolved from my promise.

How can I test this? What's the correct way of spying/stubbing/mocking Promises?

Thanks!